# How to output the data when the group state is timeout in structured streaming?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I am trying using flatMapGroupsWithState of structured streaming. I set the water mark and window as following.

```
input.withWatermark("eventTime", "10 seconds")
      .withColumn("window1", window($"eventTime", "1 minutes", "1 minutes"))
```

and set the GroupStateTimeout with `GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout()`.

The output mode is `OutputMode.Append()`.

The trigger is 10 seconds `Trigger.ProcessingTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

In the caculte function as following.

```
var totalValue = 0L
      val output = ArrayBuffer[(String, String, Long)]()
      // 当前组状态已过期，则清除状态
      if (groupState.hasTimedOut) {
        println("清除状态...")
        groupState.remove()
      } else if (groupState.exists) {
        println("增量聚合....")
        // 历史值: 从状态中获取
        val historyValue = groupState.get._2

        var currentValue = 0L
        while (currentBatchRows.hasNext) {
          val row = currentBatchRows.next()
          val count: Int = row.getAs("count")
          currentValue = currentValue + count
        }
        //        // 当前值: 从当前组的新数据计算得到
        //        val currentValue = currentBatchRows.size
        // 总值=历史+当前
        totalValue = historyValue + currentValue

        // 更新状态
        val newState = (groupKey, totalValue)
        groupState.update(newState)
      } else {
        println("初始化状态...")

        while (currentBatchRows.hasNext) {
          val row = currentBatchRows.next()
          val count: Int = row.getAs("count")
          totalValue = totalValue + count
        }
        val initialState = (groupKey, totalValue * 1L)
        groupState.update(initialState)
      }

      if (totalValue != 0) {
        val groupKeyArray = groupKey.split(",")
        output.append((groupKeyArray(0), groupKeyArray(1), totalValue))
      }

      output.iterator
```

the output is every input data caculated state data. I just want the data when the GroupState is timeout not the temp data as the group state may be updated in the next batch.

Anyone knows how to archieve that?